# touchevents on mobile devices with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, canvas, touch

I develop a mobile game which needs user input that means in this case touchinput. I try to make a touchevent that you can see on the bottom. A piece of the code works on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4hy12hyo/1/) well on touch devices, but if I implement the code into my overrided code it wont work. I try many various ways to solve it but I am at the end of my knowledge. Have anyone tips to eleminate the mistake?

```
   <html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <style>
 body {
    margin: 0;
}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id= "gameArea">
    <canvas id="myCanvas" ></canvas>
    </div>
    <script>
window.onload = window.onresize = function() {
  var C = 1; // canvas width to viewport width ratio
  var el = document.getElementById("myCanvas");


  var viewportWidth = window.innerWidth;
  var viewportHeight = window.innerHeight;

  var canvasWidth = viewportWidth * C;
  var canvasHeight = viewportHeight;
  el.style.position = "fixed";
  el.setAttribute("width", canvasWidth);
  el.setAttribute("height", canvasHeight);
  var x = canvasWidth / 100;
  var y = canvasHeight / 100;
  var ballx = canvasWidth / 100;

  window.ctx = el.getContext("2d");
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
  // draw triangles


  function init() {
    recty = canvasHeight / 100 * 20;
    rectx = (Math.random() *(x * 50)) + (x / 5);
    rectb = (Math.random() * (x * 40)) + x * 20;
    return setInterval(main_loop, 10);


  }


  function draw() {
    rectheight = canvasHeight / 100 * 10;
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
    // draw rect
    ctx.beginPath();
    fillStyle = "#000000";
    ctx.rect(rectx, recty, rectb, rectheight);
    ctx.fill();
    // draw triangles
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(x * 90, y * 50);
    ctx.lineTo(x * 99, y * 60);
    ctx.lineTo(x * 99, y * 40);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(x * 10, y * 50);
    ctx.lineTo(x * 1, y * 40);
    ctx.lineTo(x * 1, y * 60);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();
    // ballx

    // draw ball
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FF4422";
    ctx.arc(ballx * 50, y * 50, x * 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.fill();
  }

  function update() {
    recty += 1;
    if (recty > canvasHeight) {
      recty = -rectheight;
      rectx = (Math.random() *(x * 50)) + (x / 5);
      rectb = (Math.random() * (x * 50)) + x * 20;
    }
    if (recty > canvasHeight) {
      recty -= 1;


    }
  }



  function main_loop() {
    draw();
    update();

  }



  init();


}
function initia() {
        console.log('init');
        // Get a reference to our touch-sensitive element
        var touchzone = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        // Add an event handler for the touchstart event
        // touchzone.addEventListener("mousedown", touchHandler, false);
        touchzone.addEventListener("touchstart", touchHandler, false);
    }

    function touchHandler(event) {
        // Get a reference to our coordinates div
        var can = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        // Write the coordinates of the touch to the div
        var pageX = event.touches ? event.touches[0].pageX : event.pageX;
        if (pageX < x * 50) {
            ballx += 1;
        } else if (pageX > x * 50) {
            ballx -= 1;
        }

        console.log(x, ballx);

        draw();

    }
    initia();

  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: remove `ballx = canvasWidth / 100;` within the `draw` function.

Comment: if I change that, the ball dont become drawed.

Comment: You have to define the `ballx` variable somewhere else in your code. Add `var ballx = canvasWidth / 100;` after the `canvasWidth` variable.

Comment: I edit it and try it on mobile device. It dont work. But thank that  you try to help me.